# How to convert \x1 \x2 \x3 ... characters to normal characters without erasing?

Tags: c++, string, character

What are those \x1 ..\x2 ..\x3 characters and how to convert these to normal characters?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are characters with the ordinal values 1, 2, and 3. They are called [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) and are not printable, which is why the debugger is showing you their [escaped representation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

You can look the control characters up in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).