# Reading / Writing Control Characters in binary file

Tags: c++, io, binary

I'm currently processing a binary file using C++...

At some point I read a byte in and the char * read is "\x3" which seems to be a control character.

But when i got to write it back out using:

```
const char *control = "\x3";
fout.write(control, sizeof(control));
```

And then i read the binary file back in the read value is "\x11C".

How does one write the control character array back out to file the correct way?

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941513/how-to-convert-x1-x2-x3-characters-to-normal-characters-without-erasing-i

Comment: You're writing more than 1 character.

Comment: `sizeof(control)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the string it points to.

Comment: Use `strlen` to get the length of a C-Style string (array of characters, terminated by nul character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is writing 4-8 characters to the binary file instead of the 1 you seem to be expecting. `control` is treated as a normal pointer, and `sizeof(control)` is interpreting said pointer without considering the data it points to, and is returning a value of 4-8.

The best way to fix this is to declare `control` as a single character, which is what you seem to intend:

```
char control = '\x3';
fout.write(&control, sizeof(control));
```

The other way, if you actually need to write multiple characters, is like this:

```
const std::string control = "\x3";
fout.write(control.data(), control.size());
```

Either method will correctly output the number of characters you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to write string literals, is by declaring them as an array:

```
static char const  data[] = "Hello World!\n";
fout.write(data, sizeof(data) - 1U);
```

The `- 1U` is so that the terminating NUL is not written.  Remove as you wish.

Since the `data` array is declared with no capacity, so the compiler determines the length based on the content.

The `sizeof` can be used since the size of a character is 1 (by definition).

A nice advantage of this method is that the size is known at compile time.  No searching for the length is required.